# React Native SectionList data not an array but an object { items: [..]} instead

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using section list on my React Native, the thing is that section list receive this kind of data.

```
const DATA = [
            {
                date: "Main dishes",
                data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"],
            },
            {
                date: "Sides",
                data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"],
            },
            {
                date: "Drinks",
                data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"],
            },
            {
                date: "Desserts",
                data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"],
            },
        ];
```

But my api can only send this kind of data

```
const DATA = [
    {
        date: "Main dishes",
        data: { 
                items: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"]
            },
    },
    {
        date: "Sides",
        data: { 
                items: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
            },,
    },
];
```

The thing is that my Section list doesn't work with this one cause data is not an array, but an object.

Does someone got an idea how I can make this work ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: convert to the required format using an array map?

Answer (score 1):

You could try serializing the data you receive as such:

```
const serializedData = DATA.map(item => ({...item, data: item?.data?.items}))
```